# How does Docker handle SSL/TLS certificates when building container images?

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate

My company uses a proxy to inspect our SSL/TLS traffic, this often causes some hurdles when developing locally because we need to ensure that various tools trust the company's CA.

One case where this causes problems is when building Docker images: for many of our devs build steps that need to download assets from the internet (for example `apt` or `pip` install) will fail due to certificate validation errors. One workaround we have found is to copy the company's CA cert into the build container and then appending it in various locations as necessary, e.g.:

```
COPY company_ca.crt company_ca.crt
RUN cat company_ca.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
RUN cat company_ca.crt >> `python -c "import requests; print(requests.certs.where())"`
```

However, for other devs these steps are not necessary. My suspicion is that if the host system is correctly configured to trust company's CA than this should automatically carry over to the docker engine and any containers. But I don't know enough about how docker handles TLS to say this for certain.

Which brings me the actual question: how does docker handle SSL/TLS certificate verification? Does each container verify against its own cert store? Or is there some way of discovering trusted certs from the host? Or does the docker engine act as a sort of SSL/TLS termination proxy, where it makes requests on behalf of containers so that they don't need to concern themselves with certs at all? Is any of this different for the docker build tools vs the container runtime?

Comment: Instead of baking it into the container, why not include it as a volume mount, environment variable, or Kubernetes secret?

Comment: Those make sense as alternative (and perhaps preferable) ways of making the CA cert available to the container, but I suppose I'm more interested in knowing if that is truly necessary at all?